# How to control mode of execution of a shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I want to restrict users who want to use a specific script to follow a specific format of execution and print an error message on screen was they do not follow it. I want users to run my script in the below format only

```
$ bash script.sh
```

If they try to execute in other formats like,

```
$ sh script.sh

$./script.sh
```

I want to print an error message with instructions on how to execute the script

Comment: That last one should not be an issue if the script is executable and has the correct shebang (`#!`) line at the top.

Comment: I want to restrict the last two modes of execution.

Comment: I know that, but I'm just saying I don't see a reason to restrict users from executing the script as `./script.sh`. That should be totally safe. The second one, `sh script.sh`, will obviously cause problems if the script uses bashisms.

Comment: well, I wrote a bash script for running on solaris. my script is fails to execute with last two modes. so want to force users use the first example

Comment: That indicates that the first line of the script doesn't point to the correct location of the `bash` interpreter, or that the script is not executable.

Comment: I did not think in that perspective! It did not point to correct path of bash interpreter. So, what can be done about `sh script.sh`

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/echo Run this script with: bash

if ! [ "$BASHOPTS" ]
then
    echo Run this script as bash script.sh
    exit 1
fi
... rest of script here ...
```

This prevents (useful) execution with `./script.sh`, invoking the `echo` binary instead of a shell interpreter and printing the message on the first line, followed by the script name.

If run in a non-Bash shell, or Bash in POSIX mode (as with `sh`), the `BASHOPTS` variable will almost certainly not be set and the body of the `if` will run, printing a message and exiting with an error.

This works in 4-series Bash versions when used as `sh`; for earlier versions perhaps `if ! [ "$BASH" ] || ! [ "${BASH##*/}" = "bash" ]` is your best bet, which checks that the path to the interpreter ends with `/bash`. If your `sh` is non-Bash then just checking for `$BASH` is enough.

Honestly, I think you're likely solving the wrong problem, but this will do what you asked.